# biblatex: pdftooltip for et al

Tags: biblatex, pdfcomment

I failed to get a pdftooltip for the et al part of remaining author using biblatex

```
\newcommand\pprintnames[3]{
  \printnames[#1][#2]{#3} 
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \exp_args:Nnne { Nnee }
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\exp_args:Nne\pdftooltip{\bibstring{andothers}}{\exp_args:Nnee\pprintnames{}{\value{minnames}-\value{listtotal}}{\currentname}}}
    {}}
```

Do you have an idea how to fix it ?

Comment: `\printnames` is not expandable, so however hard we try, we won't get anything useful to pass on to `\pdftooltip`. `biblatex` does not have an expandable name to obtain name lists, we'd have to cobble something together using lots of `\def` and `\appto`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments `\printnames` is a command that prints names. It is most definitely not expandable and cannot passed to `\pdftooltip` to yield a useful name list.

The usual way to work around that in `biblatex` is to build up an expandable name list by looping over the name with `\indexnames` (because that is not supposed to print anything) and appending the names one by one to a macro.

There are some small stumbling blocks here because we call `\indexnames` within `\printnames` (i.e. while we're already looping over a name list), so we have to avoid an infinite loop when `\currentname` is assigned.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxbibnames=999]{biblatex}

\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{grabnames}{%
  \xappto\grabbednamelist{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststart}}
      {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
         { and }
         {, }}
      {}%
    \expandonce{\namepartfamily}}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim
     \edef\currcurrname{\currentname}%
     \numdef\nextnamenum{\value{listcount}+1}%
     \def\grabbednamelist{}%
     \indexnames[grabnames][\nextnamenum-\value{listtotal}]{\currcurrname}%
     \pdftooltip{\bibstring{andothers}}{\grabbednamelist}}
    {}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,aksin,herrmann,murray,yoon}

\pdftooltip{Hullo}{Hullo Again}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: A screenshot of the output shown with the mouse hovering over the "et al." from "Aksın et al.". A tooltip shows "Türkmen, Artok, Çetinkaya, Ni, Büyükgüngör and Özkal".]